# Email not sending

Tags: c#, validation, email, smtp, contact-form

I have created a contact form that the user can enter his/her name and their email address, everything is working fine apart from I am getting an error at a certain point when the submit button is clicked, below I have highlighted where that error is. I have taken out my password of course for security purposes.

```
 using System;
 using System.Net.Mail;

 namespace WhiteLabelConProject
 {
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("martinhall1390@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.To.Add("martinhall1390@gmail.com");

            mailMessage.Body = "<b>SenderName : </b>" + txtName.Text + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Sender Email : </b>" + txtEmail.Text + "<br/>";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new     System.Net.NetworkCredential("martinhall1390@gmail.com","");
            **smtpClient.Send(mailMessage); <<<<<<<< ERROR WITH THIS BIT OF CODE**

            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            Label1.Text = "Thank you for registering";

            txtName.Enabled = false;
            txtEmail.Enabled = false;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            //Log - Event Viewer or table
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label1.Text = "There is an unknown problem. Please try later";
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You are catching all Exceptions and dropping them, making the specific problem difficult to debug.

Comment: Sorry, basically the page loads for ages and the error I receive is "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out." and the "smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);"highlighted above is shown in red.

Comment: Might want to try port 465 (instead of 587) for your client: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en. This could also be a firewall issue.

Comment: Tried changing it to 465, it does the same thing, what is the firewall problem your talking about, this is so annoying because its almost working :(

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)

Comment: I had a similar issue while developing at home. ATT blocked all outgoing SMTP connections. When I moved my code to my VM it worked since SMTP was not blocked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmtpClient Timing Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886925/smtpclient-timing-out)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because there is no subject for the code such as:

```
 mailMessage.Subject = "EmailSubject";
```

I also would suggest having the "IsBodyHtml" as false as there may be a fault with the html code here. As a result you should have the following code for the body:

```
 mailMessage.Body = "Sender name  :" + txtName.Text + "\n Sender email  :" + txtEmail.Text;
```